# mysql fields to HTML template (python unicode decode error)

Tags: python, html, mysql, unicode

I need to send fields from a mysql query to a HTML template select. This is my python code:

```
class Estilos(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    db = .....
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT estilo, n1 FROM estilos;')
    lista = []
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
     lista.append([cgi.escape(row[0]),
                  cgi.escape(row[1])
                  ])

    variables = {'lista':lista}

    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('estilo.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(variables))
    db.close()
```

This is my HTML template:

```
<html>
  <form action="/sign" method="post">
    <br />
    <div>Estilo: <select name="estilo" style="width:400px"> 
        {% for e in lista %}
              <option value="{{ e }}">{{ e }}                      
              </option>
            {% endfor %}
             </select>
             </div>

    <div> N1: <select name="n1" style="width:400px"> 
        {% for e in lista %}
              <option value="{{ e }}" >{{ e }}                      
              </option>
            {% endfor %}
             </select>
             </div>

    <div><input type="submit" value="Selecionar"></div>
  </form>
```

This code shows the entire row in the select field: ['STRONG PALE ALE', 'ALE']

When I change the form select value to

```
                  <option value="{{ e[0] }}">{{ e[0] }}                      
              </option>
```

then I get a unicode decode error.

```
<option value="{{ e[0] }}">{{ e[0] }} UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried to encode the cgi.escape to utf8 but I cannot make it work. Does anybody know how to fix this? What is the correct way to encode the string?

Comment: Please edit the Q to show the `repr` of the erring `row` -- not knowing if it's composed of bytes or unicode strings, or the encoding if any byte strings, makes it hard to help you.

Comment: If I print str() I get:  {'n1': 'ALE', 'estilo': 'STRONG PALE ALE'}. If I print repr() I get:  {'n1': "'ALE'", 'estilo': "'STRONG PALE ALE'"}

Comment: Taking literally every detail you report (i.e assuming you made absolutely no mistakes in reporting nor mixed up different versions of your code) I'm stumped: that `\xc4` (uppercase A with umlaut, if e.g latin-1) springs out of nowhere.  Try using `cgi.escape(row[0].decode('ascii','replace'))` &c and see where question marks replace characters you were expecting (if `decode` shows nothing, try `encode` instead, but that will likely give you the same UnicodeDecodeError you're getting now).

Comment: Thanks Alex! Decode worked fine. That is what I needed.  By the way, I did mix diffferent versions of the code, but anyway I think the point was to check the string format. Thanks again. Very useful.

Comment: OK, let me make it an answer so you can accept it and close the thread!

Answer (score 0):

Taking literally every detail reported (i.e assuming you made absolutely no mistakes in reporting nor mixed up different versions of your code) I'd be stumped: that `\xc4` (uppercase A with umlaut, if e.g latin-1) springs out of nowhere

However, the OP confirmed in a comment that he **was** actually mixing up different versions of the code, in which case...:

A good idea is to use `cgi.escape(row[0].decode('ascii','replace'))` &c, and see where question marks replace characters that were expected.  The OP confirmed in a comment this worked for them.

For completeness, thinking of future readers with similar problems: if `decode` shows nothing, they could try `encode` instead, but that will likely give the same `UnicodeDecodeError` originally reported by the OP.